# Array of Objects in Javascript on the basis of an element

Tags: javascript

Lets Suppose I have 1000's of objects. Now I want to store objects with same name in an array So that I'll have multiple arrays having objects with same name. How can this be done in JavaScript?
Data can be like this

[image: Data can be like this]

Comment: @MaazKhan47 do you have json object? which you want to store in array?

Comment: @BunkerBoy Yes Json Objects

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var input = [
        { name: 'ABC', age: 12 },
        { name: 'XYZ', age: 13 },
        { name: 'ABC', age: 14 },
        { name: 'XYZ', age: 15 },
    ];
    
    var output = {};
    
    input.forEach(function(obj) {
       var array = output[obj.name];
    
       if (!array) {
          array = output[obj.name] = [];
       }
    
       array.push(obj)
    })

    for(name in output) {
        console.log('There are ' + output[name].length + ' people named ' + name);
    }
```

Comment: For you, anything :)

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, objects aren't copied into arrays.  They exist in memory and when added to a an array the reference to that object is what lives in an array.

In the following code, `myObj === arr1[0] === arr2`.  Which means the following is true:

```js
var myObj = {name:'Dave', age: 55};
var arr1 = [myObj];
var arr2 = [myObj];

arr2[0].age = 44;
console.log(myObj.age);
// prints 44
console.log(arr1[0].age);
// prints 44
```

So to get what you need, you just need to organize your data into arrays.  In javascript, you can filter arrays:

```js
// original data
var data = [
 {name: 'ABC', age: 12},
 {name: 'XYZ', age: 13},
 {name: 'ABC', age: 14},
 {name: 'XYZ', age: 15},
 {name: 'XYZ', age: 16},
];
    
// this returns a function to be used in Array.filter to filter for objects with the specified name
function nameFilter(name) {
  return function(datum) {
    return datum.name === name;
  }
}
    
// filter for each type
var abcPeople = data.filter(nameFilter('ABC'));
var xyzPeople = data.filter(nameFilter('XYZ'));
      
console.log(data.length);
//5
console.log(abcPeople.length);
//2
console.log(xyzPeople.length);
//3
```

If you run the above code, you would have 3 arrays and all object in `abcPeople` would also be in `data` such that any change to one would be reflected in the other.  The same is true for `xyzPeople`.  **Just to be clear, `filter` creates a new array, so `data` is not modified.**

**UPDATE: Added example where lists are dynamically determined**

```js
// original data
var data = [
  {name: 'ABC', age: 12},
  {name: 'XYZ', age: 13},
  {name: 'ABC', age: 14},
  {name: 'XYZ', age: 15},
  {name: 'XYZ', age: 16},
];
      
var sortedData = {};
  
data.forEach(function(datum){
  // initializes an array for any unseen name
  if(!sortedData[datum.name]) {
    sortedData[datum.name] = [];
  }
  // add the datum to the list for its name
  sortedData[datum.name].push(datum);
});

// all names
console.log(Object.keys(sortedData));
// "ABC", "XYZ"

// items named "ABC"
console.log(sortedData['ABC']);
// [{"name": "ABC","age": 12}, {"name": "ABC","age": 14}]
```

Comment: Well the complication here is that I can have so many types (Names) then how am I suppose to filter for each type?

Comment: If you have a list of names, you can iterate over that.  If not, then you can iterate over the original list and split up the objects that way.  You would end up with a object of arrays at that point